# How to align two items next to each other in Semantic UI?

Tags: css, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm trying to make a `Header`element sit next to an `Button` icon but I cannot make it happen.

Without attempting any Grids listing them like this

```
<Header as='h4'>Header text</Header>
<Button icon className='transparentButton'>
   <Icon name='add'/>
</Button>
```

makes it look like this - each item on different line: 
[image]

If I try to make a Grid with one row and two columns there is a massive space between the two and also the header text is wrapped. At least is vertically aligned I guess...

```html
<Grid>
  <Grid.Row verticalAlign='middle'>
    <Grid.Column>
      <Header as='h4'>Header text</Header>
    </Grid.Column>
    <Grid.Column>
      <Button icon className='transparentButton'>
                      <Icon name='add'/>
                    </Button>
    </Grid.Column>
  </Grid.Row>
</Grid>
```

This looks like that:[image]

I'd really love to hear how suggestions on how to make the two items sit next to each other properly. I want to make it look like this:

[image]

Example code https://codesandbox.io/s/semantic-ui-react-example-ttnxc (not sure why the Icon is not rendering there though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually I think that Header Component is displaying as block

Just try to edit it's css and make:

```
display: inline-block;
```

and it should render successfully

unfortunately your example code didn't load so i couldn't try this but it should work

Comment: Damn, works like magic... I reaaally need to up my css game :) thanks a lot

Comment: The more you learn css ... the more you recognise that you don't know anything in css 